# Is $ R =\{a_{2n} x^{2n} + ... + a_2 x^2 + a_0\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$, subring of $\Bbb Z[x]$, noetherian?

Tags: noetherian

Is  $ R =\{a_{2n} x^{2n} + ... + a_2 x^2 + a_0\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$}, subring of $\Bbb Z[x]$, noetherian ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yes, because $\mathbf Z[X]$ is a finitely generated free $R$-module, and is noetherian.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ via the isomorphism

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}[x] &\to R \\
f(x) &\mapsto f(x^2).
\end{align*}

In particular $R$ is noetherian.